# Passing one variable of the two variables defined for a function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, symbolic-math

I have the following function in MATLAB:

```
f(x,A) = @(x,A) x'*A*x
```

where `A` is an `n-by-n` matrix and `x` is an `n-by-1` vector. Is it possible that I pass only `A` into the function as an array of reals, and leave `x` as symbolic? In other words, I don't want to type the elements of `A` into the `f(x) = @(x) ...` and want to be able to change the values of `A`, say within a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done as follows:

```
>> n = 3;
>> x = sym('x', [n 1]); %// define x as a symbolic n-by-1 vector
>> f = @(x,A) x'*A*x; %'// define function f

>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]; %// define an n-by-n matrix A
>> f(x,A)
ans =
x1*(conj(x1) + 4*conj(x2) + 7*conj(x3)) + x2*(2*conj(x1) + 5*conj(x2) + 8*conj(x3)) + x3*(3*conj(x1) + 6*conj(x2) + 9*conj(x3))

>> A = [5 6 7; 8 9 10; 10 11 12]; %// now try a different n-by-n matrix A
>> f(x,A)
ans =
x1*(5*conj(x1) + 8*conj(x2) + 10*conj(x3)) + x2*(6*conj(x1) + 9*conj(x2) + 11*conj(x3)) + x3*(7*conj(x1) + 10*conj(x2) + 12*conj(x3))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't now if I've fully understood you, but what about redefining `f` at each loop iteration?

```
X = [1 2 1 3 1];

for t = 1:5
    A = rand(5);
    f = @(x)(x'*A*x);
    disp(f(X));
end
```

Comment: Would you use an anonymous function in this case, or a nested function?

Comment: @Dan This is funny: redefining the function in the loop -- like you did -- is the only way. :-) Apparently changing only the matrix A in the loop will not alter the anonymous function. Which kind of gives an idea why anonymous functions are soooo slow: they duplicate the hosting workspace (or at least parts of it).

Comment: @CST-Link I think of them like closures in functional programming languages (I'm no expert though) or like blocking in objective-c. They save the state of any variables inside used in them when they are defined

Comment: @beaker what do you mean by nested function?

Comment: Like this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html It basically creates a function that's private to the nesting function.

Comment: @LuisMendo That's kinda surprising. I don't have the symbolic toolbox, I'll try though... [After testing] seems like the symbolic toolbox changes slightly the things for the anonymous functions, because I got an error trying to evaluate an anonymous function depending on an undefined variable, even if I defined it afterwards.

Comment: @beaker I didn't know about that, to me that replaces a lot of the use cases for anonymous functions. I'm surprised they're not more popular

Comment: @CST-Link Actually I'm using `A` as an explicit input to the anonymous function. Removing my previous comment to avoid confusion

Comment: @beaker I take it back, they can modify variables outside of their scope. I don't like that and wouldn't use it.

Comment: @Dan That's the big difference, right? All of the variables of the nesting function are effectively global and accessible to the nested function. You have to exercise restraint and make local copies of the variables you don't want to change.

Comment: @beaker well the big difference is that anonymous functions are restricted to 1 line, so no flow control, which is why initially I like the sound of these nested functions. But the fact that it doesn't scope its variables ruins it for me.